# Adding checkbox format in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Trying to add checkbox format to a column using Google Apps Script to this working formula

```
sales.getRange("I2").setFormula("=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,E:E,TRUE),TRUE)");      
    var fillDownRange = sales.getRange (2, 9, salesLR);
           sales.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

Tried doing it this way without success:

```
sales.getRange("I2").setFormula("=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,E:E,TRUE),TRUE)");      
var fillDownRange = sales.getRange (2, 9, salesLR);
       sales.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange).newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
```

Also tried this without succss:

```
sales.getRange("I2").setFormula("=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,E:E,TRUE),TRUE)");      
      var fillDownRange = sales.getRange (2, 9, salesLR);
      sales.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange).insertCheckboxes();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has ben solved. I was targeting the wrong column, solution was:

```
sales.getRange (2, 5, salesLR).insertCheckboxes();
sales.getRange (2, 6, salesLR).insertCheckboxes();
```